# Preview shortcut not working in TeXstudio on Ubuntu

Tags: texstudio, ubuntu, shortcut

TeXstudio has a live-preview feature for selections of the text. The live preview can be triggered using the shortcut Alt+p. This shortcut works perfectly on Windows, though when using it on Ubuntu it gives an error message:

> The key sequence 'Alt+P' is ambiguous. Use 'Configure Shortcuts'
>   from the 'Settings' menu to solve the ambiguity.

However, I can't find the live preview shortcut anywhere in the settings. Can anyone help with that?

Comment: `Shortcuts -> Idefix -> Preview selection/Parenthesis`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the shortcut in `Options -> Configure TeXstudio -> Shortcuts -> Idefix -> Preview selection/Parenthesis`.

[image]